# I can't change the global background material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

the material ui libraries have a white global background by default at startup, I tried to change it to red, but it doesn't work. How can it be changed? the default is a white background, I want to make a different color

```
   MuiDivider: {
              styleOverrides: {
                  root: {
                   backgroundColor:"#cc5a5a",
                    },
                  },
                },
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to change the `backgroundColor` of `MuiDivider`.
Do you want to change the `border-color` of `MuiDivider`?
Or do you want to change `background-color` of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should import 'makeStyles' to be able to change the background. You can try this one:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 root: {
  borderColor: "#cc5a5a",
  backgroundColor:"#cc5a5a",
 }
}));

export default function Sample() {
 const classes = useStyles();

 return (
  <div className={classes.root}>...</div>
 )
}
```

Also do try to do some research in the future before posting a question here.